# SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have two tables in my databases with the following structures

1.ps_branch

COLUMNS:  ps_code a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7

2.students_info

COLUMNS: std_name std_cg  st_code

I am using xampp server.

I wrote a query in php:

```
$qs1="select * from station_details where st_code IN 
(
( select DISTINCT st_code FROM students_info , ps_branch WHERE ps_code=st_code AND    std_cg >".$_POST['Cgpa'].
      "AND".$_POST['branch']."=".'1'."))";
$query1=mysqli_query($con1,$qs1);
```

But the query is showing me error.
When i query the following directly in phpmyadmin mysql i get the answer i required

```
select * from station_details where st_code IN 
(
( select DISTINCT st_code FROM students_info , ps_branch WHERE ps_code=st_code AND  std_cg>6
      AND a7=1)
 )
```

$_POST['branch'] will give one of the values a1 a2 ...or a7
$_POST['Cgpa'] is a numerical value

Comment: well you could just look at the error that is generated ... but between AND and $_POST... you need a space  " AND "

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra spaces around the 'AND'

```
$qs1="select * from station_details where st_code IN 
(
( select DISTINCT st_code FROM students_info , ps_branch WHERE ps_code=st_code AND std_cg >".$_POST['Cgpa'].
      " AND ".$_POST['branch']."=".'1'."))";
$query1=mysqli_query($con1,$qs1);
```

The way to debug this is to show the value of $qs1 by using `die($qs1);` after $qs1 it is set and before executing the query. Then you can see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the die($qs1) tip..very useful!